# Is it possible to marshal/unmarshal Prometheus state in go-client?

Tags: go, prometheus

I'd like to be able to save the save the state of various Prometheus metrics (CounterVec, HistogramVec, ...) to a file from my app, and resume it later when necessary. Would that be possible?

I see that there is the [`Write` method in `metric.go`](https://github.com/prometheus/client_golang/blob/39fc1959742f9bea0ef7ff1ad885f2f02fce6d56/prometheus/metric.go#L52), but can't find the `Read` one.

Comment: [github.com/prometheus/common/expfmt.Encoder](https://godoc.org/github.com/prometheus/common/expfmt#Encoder). See [promhttp.HandlerFor](https://github.com/prometheus/client_golang/blob/v1.4.1/prometheus/promhttp/http.go#L86) for a usage example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No Prometheus client library supports this, nor should you need this. Client libraries are designed to work entirely in memory, and functions like `rate()` will gracefully handle the counter resets due to a process restarting.